# Spring Boot embedded Tomcat: how to use Tomcat 7 in Integration Tests?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot **1.4** application and I'm writing an integration test for my Rest endpoint.
I'm using the new test annotations, like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = {"server.port=8443"})
```

When the test runs, Spring Boots starts Tomcat 8.5.4. I would like to use Tomcat 7. Is there a way to force to change the version of the embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Tomcat 7. You need to add dependency to `tomcat-juli` and set a property:

```
<tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
```

More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-7).

Comment: Setting the Tomcat version in Maven works only when running the Spring Boot application (mvn boot:run) but it does not influence the integration test. This is actually the first thing I have tried :)

Comment: How do you start your integration test?

Comment: IDE (IntelliJ) or Maven (mvn clean test). Same result:

`Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4`

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you. I've just checked this and after setting the property in `pom.xml` IntelliJ has used Tomcat 7 dependencies.